# Fscanf prints everything but exits program with code 1 in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, scanf

I have this function which reads some strings in this format:

2
London Berlin 220 1.5
London Milan 280 2.5
...

and same stuff should be read againg...

2 is the number of strings after itself. For this purpose I have the following function:

```
void allocate_info(FILE* fptr, info_t* cities_info, int N){
    int tmp_flights;
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(fptr, "%d", &tmp_flights) == 1){
        printf("%d\n", tmp_flights); // this print!!!
        char tmp_departure[LENGTH], tmp_arrival[LENGTH];
        int tmp_price;
        float tmp_duration;
        for(int i = 0; i < tmp_flights; i++){
            fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %d %f", tmp_departure, tmp_arrival, &tmp_price, &tmp_duration);
            strcpy(cities_info[i].departure, tmp_departure);
            strcpy(cities_info[i].arrival, tmp_arrival);
            cities_info[i].price = tmp_price;
            cities_info[i].duration = tmp_duration;
        }
    }
}
```

"this print!!!" actually prints all numbers but at the end program fails (error 1). this is my main function:

```
int main(void) {
    FILE* fptr = fopen("D:/ap2/lab02ex01/file.txt", "r");
    int N;
    info_t* cities_info = (info_t*)malloc(sizeof(info_t) * N);
    N = read_number_of_cities(fptr); // some other function
    allocate_info(fptr, cities_info, N); // ERROR HERE?!?

    return 0;
}
```

I am very confused about it, because it prints everything correctly but program for some reason fails. Help me out please.

Comment: You never initialized `N` before `sizeof(info_t) * N`.

Comment: Move the `N=` line before `info_t* cities_info` line.

Comment: Why does `allocate_info()` take `N` as a parameter if it reads it from the file?

Comment: Does `read_number_of_citites()` rewind `fptr` before returning? If not, `allocate_info()` needs to rewind before it starts. Or it should just use `N` instead of reading `tmp_flights` itself.

Comment: You checked the return value of `fscanf` once, but not the second time. You should get in the habit of doing this every time.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I am exhausted ir what...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the variable `N` in your `main` function before initializing it is invoking [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) since the value of `N` is indeterminate at the point where it's used.

If you compile with warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra`), you would see a warning like the following, among possibly others.

```
warning: variable 'N' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
```

If you compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` this would have been treated as a compilation error and would have to have been fixed before you could ever *run* the program in the first place.

You would also have seen warnings about ignoring the return value of `fscanf`, and with `-Werror` have been forced to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to initialize N before calling function.